# How to send some value if unchecked for each checkbox with same name?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

Here I have multiple checkbox with same name. Checkbox can be added to n no. of times.

Here if already checked I want to send 1 and if not 0.

Right now in my django backend I am getting the list with `request.POST.getlist('need_a')` like this.

If all checked `[1, 1, 1]` which is fine .

if only one checked then I am getting `[1]` instead of  `[1, 0, 0]`

```
 <input name="need_a" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" 
 value="1" {% if some_condition %}checked{% endif %}/>

 <input name="need_a" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input "
 value="1" {% if some_condition %}checked{% endif %}/>

 <input name="need_a" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" 
 value="1" {% if some_condition %}checked{% endif %}/>
```

Comment: Hi, where is the jQuery in this example? You can easily get the desired array with jQuery and than send it via ajax post request to your python code.

Comment: @Rüzgar I am not being able to write jquery for this

Answer (score 0):

This work.
Just make a change handler in jquery and prove if it is checked or not.
Check it in the Developer Tools.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).val(1);
  } else {
    $(this).val(0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input name="need_a" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1" checked>
  <label for="scales">Scales</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input name="need_a" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1" checked>
  <label for="horns">Horns</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input name="need_a" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1" checked>
  <label for="Guitar">Guitar</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is, when it is not checked, the value is not sent. Even if you set the value to 0, django won't receive it.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it didn't worked.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I'm not familiar with django.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is incorrect, what you need is to create a hidden input with the default value for the unchecked fields an keep the grouped by name, see my example below:

```html
<input name="need_a" type="hidden" value="0">
<input name="need_a" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1" {% if some_condition %}checked{% endif %}>

<input name="need_b" type="hidden" value="0">
<input name="need_b" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input " value="1" {% if some_condition %}checked{% endif %} />

<input name="need_c" type="hidden" value="0">
<input name="need_c" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1" {% if some_condition %}checked{% endif %} />
```

And in django you need to create an array to respect your format such as:

```
formValues = [request.POST.getlist('need_a'), request.POST.getlist('need_b') , request.POST.getlist('need_c')]
```

Then you'll get `[1,0,1] / [0,0,1] / etc` values.

This is what the browser is sending to django (`need_a checked`, `need_b not checked`, `need_c checked`):

```
need_a  […]
0   "0"
1   "1"
need_b  "0"
need_c  […]
0   "0"
1   "1
```

And this is what my backend(PHP) caught on the request:

```
Array ( [need_a] => 1 [need_b] => 0 [need_c] => 1 )
```

Comment: Isn't it possible all the checkbox with same names ?

Comment: No, that's not how you use checkboxes/radios, they're meant to send only 1 value. The fact that you send your format and django catches `[1,1,1]` is very odd for me, i've used PHP as a primary backend, and duplicate fields aren't catched unless you're using an array format for naming such as `<input name="need_a[]" value="1" />` which are also grouped under one name as an array, php catches only the last fieldname.  The hidden fields i have added act like a fallback in case the checkboxes aren't checked.

Comment: I've updated my answer, as you can see `need_b` has only 1 value, the hidden input, because it wasn't checked. After that i can construct an array with those fields how i need them to be. A similar approach can be done in django. If i had only `need_a` everywhere php will have caught only the last value from that request. Keep in mind that post requests CAN be read differently by different servers, but differences are not major.